# Neutrino physics font

Tags: fonts

[image]

Hello, I am wondering what font all the neutrino physicists are using these days? It looks like libris but it's not.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you have the pdf file? Check the used fonts ...

Comment: font on this picture looks like https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/margarita-dyakovich/md-pen/regular/

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh It is very closer :-) but for the \nu I think that is another font.

Comment: Wow you sniped it !! Thank you all very much. I have a pdf but this is from a figure in pdf. Can I still check from the figure?

Comment: Depends if the figure is vector graphics or raster. If vector (e.g. from TikZ, or external like Matplotlib PDF output), it’s likely that the corresponding fonts are embedded in the PDF. If raster, no as it has been rendered to pixels already.

Comment: Got it. I'm going to check. MD Pen seems extremely close........ I am so impressed that you found it just from looking wow

Answer (score 2):

In the Symbol list of the symbols used in `LaTeX` exist a package named `svrsymbols`. Here you find the commands:

```
\neutrino
\antineutrino
```

---

Here there is a small example with a predefinte font:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{svrsymbols}
\begin{document}
$\neutrino, \antineutrino$
\end{document}
```

[image]

In your image it seems very closer to `\nu` of the frequence.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \[ \text{it is just}\quad \nu \quad \text{from amsmath package, is't it?} \]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you !!!!!